# Desarrollar una barra de experiencia

Tags: java, porcentaje

estoy desarrollando un minijuego en **Processing** y estoy con un dilema, tengo una barra de exp funcional hasta cierto punto, cuando la barra llega al máx de experiencia se reseta a 0 (lo cual está bien) pero el tema es que por ejemplo tengo este caso:

-exp actual: 1000
-exp para siguiente nivel: 10
y mato a un npc que me da 1000 de exp

La idea es que se sume esa diferencia para el siguiente nivel y (en el caso que pase) suba más niveles con esa diferencia, digamos que pase a nivel 3 de una.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea los leo!

Muchas gracias! si se necesita parte del código avisenme

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con clases, me imagino que el jugador se relaciona con una clase llamada nivel, la cual esta compuesta por los atributos XP o experiencia y nivel. Puedes mostrar como estas haciendo la barra de experiencia?

Answer (score 0):

creo que esto era lo que querias preguntar no?, necesitarias:

```
- function getExpTotLvl(Lvl){}
- function getExpSigLvl(ExpActual){return Exptot - expSigLvl}
- function +Exp(Exp, ExpSigLvl){
if(Exp > ExpSigLvl){
return Lvl++
return ExpSobrante}
else{return Lvl++}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final logré otro método, usé variables para asignar la xp de los npc (actualmente son 2) e hice un if con este algoritmo:

```
              if (xpActual + xpCruceros > xpNivel){

            xpActual = (xpActual - xpNivel) + xpCruceros;
            lvlUp = true;
            nivel++;
          }
            else {

              xpActual +=xpCruceros;

            }
```

Gracias por sus respuestas!!